# Reverse loop through a GridView and retrieve the last records, VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know how to loop through a GridView and extract each row using the for each loop as below, but I was looking for a easy way to loop through the datagrid and say extract the last 20 rows? Is it possible to go through in reverse order in vb.net?

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In InventHistoryGridView.Rows

Next row
```

Comment: well you can do a for next loop starting from Rows.Count and down to 0 with -1 increment. As usual in these cases the question is anyway: why do you loop against/through the UI Control (Grid) and not on the original datasource?

Comment: The data is brought back from numerous tables and just displayed in a Gridview so can't really loop through the Orginal data as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows is just a representation of the Rows collection in a GridView

```
For i = ((Rows.Count - 1) - 20) To Rows.Count -1
   'do some cool stuff
Next
```

Unless you specifically have to start from the last row and head backwards, in which you do as Davide Piras suggested in his comment, displayed below.

```
For i = Rows.Count -1 To ((Rows.Count - 1) - 20) Step -1
    'do some cool stuff
Next
```

Comment: You could put Rows.Count - 21, but writing it out like that more explains what you're doing.